# interactive bash script for backups

Tags: bash, shell, backup

I wrote a `bash` script to read a bunch of CSV files from a folder and create a backup file in a separate backups directory.

```
#!/bin/sh

files=$(ls /../test/*.csv 2> /dev/null | wc -l)

if [ **"$files" != "0"** ]

then

        # What to backup.
        backup_files="/../test/test2"
        # Where to backup to.
        dest="../test/"
        # Create archive filename.
        day=$(date +%A)
        name="some-file.csv"
        archive_file="$name-day.tgz"

        # Print start status message.
        echo "Backing up $backup_files to $dest/$archive_file" 
        echo 
        date

        # Backup the files using tar.
        tar czf $dest/$archive_file $backup_files

        # Print end status message.
        echo
        echo "Backup finished"
        date

else
        echo nothing there
        break
fi
```

The script should go through each CSV file (`file(1).csv`, `file(2).csv`, etc) and write to my backup file one by one, but the problem is that it only writes from the last file (`file(3).csv`).

Comment: I found out! The problem was in 5th and 15th rows - I removed only wildcards(in 5th) and use $date! Great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you are not expanding the `$day` variable. Use this:

```
archive_file="$name-$day.tgz"
```

Comment: Ok, so I use $date, but script do backup of all folder. I need only add csv if it exists. Also I don't understand why he doing backup while folder are empty Oo

Comment: Thanks for your ansver about $date)